# Navigation menu using DIV containers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to define that by default there should be shown the content of "submenu11" under ther "menu1"?

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
        <ul id="css3menu1" class="menu">
        <li class="topfirst"><a class="pressed" href="#menu1" style="height:40px;line-height:40px;"><span><img src="menu_files/css3menu1/db.png"/>MENU1</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#submenu11">SUBMENU11</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#submenu12">SUBMENU12</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#submenu13">SUBMENU13</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#submenu14">SUBMENU14</a></li>
                </ul></li>
                <li class="menu"><a href="#menu2" style="height:40px;line-height:40px;"><img src="menu_files/css3menu1/schedule.png"/>MENU2</a></li>
                <li class="menu"><a href="#menu3" style="height:40px;line-height:40px;"><img src="menu_files/css3menu1/analysis.png"/>MENU3</a></li>
                <li class="toplast"><a href="#menu4" style="height:40px;line-height:40px;"><img src="menu_files/css3menu1/gps.png"/>MENU4</a></li>
            </ul>

    <div id='submenu11'>
    <p> Content </p>
    </div>

    <div id='submenu12'>
    <p> Content </p>
    </div>

    <div id='submenu13'>
    <p> Content </p>
    </div>

    <div id='submenu14'>
    <p> Content </p>
    </div>

    <script>
        $('ul.menu').each(function() {
            var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');
            $active = $links.first().addClass('active');
            $content = $($active.attr('href'));
            $links.not(':first').each(function() {
                $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
            });

            $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
                $active.removeClass('active');
                $content.hide();
                $active = $(this);
                $content = $($(this).attr('href'));
                $active.addClass('active');
                $content.show();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

CSS stylesheet:

```
html,body {
    font: normal .8em/1.5em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

p {
    margin: 0 0 2em;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0;
    font:bold 12px Arial;
}

h2 {
    margin:0;
    color: #55aaff;
    font:bold 12px Arial;
}

h3 {
    margin:0;
    font:normal 10px Arial;
}

h4 {
    margin:0;
    font:normal 12px Arial;
}

a {
    color: #339;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

div#header {
    padding:1em;
    background:#00557f 100% 10px no-repeat;
    border-bottom:6px double gray;
}

div#header p {
    font:normal 10px Arial;
    text-align:right;
    color:#b7ddf2;
    margin:0;
}

div.scrollbar {
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    padding: 5px;
}

div#content {
    padding:1em 1em 5em; /* bottom padding for footer */
}

div#content p {
    text-align:justify;
    padding:0 1em;
}

div#footer {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0; /* stick to bottom */
    padding:1em;
    background:#ddd 98% 10px no-repeat;
    border-bottom:6px double gray;
}
div#footer p {
    font-style:italic;
    font-size:1.1em;
    margin:0;
}

/* ----------- Menu ----------- */
ul#css3menu1,ul#css3menu1 ul{
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    background-color:#dedede;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#b7ddf2;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
ul#css3menu1 ul{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:100%;
    -moz-box-shadow:3.5px 3.5px 5px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:3.5px 3.5px 5px #000000;
    box-shadow:3.5px 3.5px 5px #000000;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;border-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius:6px;
    border-color:#d4d4d4;
    padding:0 10px 10px;
}
ul#css3menu1 li:hover>*{
    display:block;
}
ul#css3menu1 li{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    font-size:0;
    float:left;
}
ul#css3menu1 li:hover{
    z-index:1;
}
ul#css3menu1{
    font-size:0;
    z-index:999;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
}
ul#css3menu1>li{
    margin:0;
}
* html ul#css3menu1 li a{
    display:inline-block;
}
ul#css3menu1 a:active, ul#css3menu1 a:focus{
    outline-style:none;
}
ul#css3menu1 a{
    display:block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:left;
    text-decoration:none;
    font:bold 12px Arial;
    color:#000000;
    text-shadow:#FFF 0 0 1px;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#ebf4fb;
    background-image:url("mainbk.png");
    background-repeat:repeat;
    background-position:0 0;
    border-width:0 0 0 1px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#C0C0C0;
}
ul#css3menu1 ul li{
    float:none;
    margin:10px 0 0;
}
ul#css3menu1 ul a{
    text-align:left;
    padding:4px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    background-image:none;
    border-width:0;
    border-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0px;
    font:11px Arial;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
ul#css3menu1 li:hover>a,ul#css3menu1 a.pressed{
    background-color:#b7ddf2;
    border-color:#C0C0C0;
    border-style:solid;
    color:#000000;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:#FFF 0 0 1px;
    background-position:0 100px;
}
ul#css3menu1 img{
    border:none;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-right:10px;
}
ul#css3menu1 img.over{
    display:none;
}
ul#css3menu1 li:hover > a img.def{
    display:none;
}
ul#css3menu1 li:hover > a img.over{
    display:inline;
}
ul#css3menu1 li a.pressed img.over{
    display:inline;
}
ul#css3menu1 li a.pressed img.def{
    display:none;
}
ul#css3menu1 span{
    display:block;
    overflow:visible;
    background-position:right center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-right:0px;
}
ul#css3menu1 li:hover>a,ul#css3menu1 li>a.pressed{
    background-color:#b7ddf2;
    background-position:0 100px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#C0C0C0;
    color:#000000;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:#FFF 0 0 1px;
}
ul#css3menu1 ul li:hover>a,ul#css3menu1 ul li>a.pressed{
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    background-image:none;
    color:#868686;
    text-decoration:none;
}
ul#css3menu1 li.topfirst>a{
    border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0;
}
ul#css3menu1 li.toplast>a{
    border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;
    -moz-border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:0;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
}
/* --------- End of Menu --------- */
```

EDIT1: I included the script and stylesheet.[image]

EDIT2: Please look at the picture. It should clarify the issue.

Comment: what is your server-side language , is it Asp.Net?

Comment: I'm using JQuery from this example: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/JgReZ/
 Sorry,I'm newbie, not sure that I've completely understood your question.

Comment: its ok never mind ,I thought you are using pages on sub menu items click , that is why I asked you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
 $active = $links.first().addClass('active');
```

It takes the first link in your menu and makes it active. Your first `<a>` tag in the ul with class menu is not the first menu item, but:

```
<a class="pressed" href="#menu1" style="height:40px;line-height:40px;"><span><img src="menu_files/css3menu1/db.png"/>MENU1</span></a>
```

So you need to make sure you target the first menu item. You can for example assign an id to it:

```
<li><a href="#submenu11" id="submenu-default">SUBMENU11</a></li>
```

and then you have to rewrite that line of javascript to:

```
$active = $('#submenu-default').addClass('active');
```

That should do the trick. Obviously you can use any other way to locate that link.

EDIT: Maybe even better solution would be to rewrite your html as follows:

```
<ul id="css3menu1">
    <li class="topfirst"><a class="pressed" href="#menu1" style="height:40px;line-height:40px;"><span><img src="menu_files/css3menu1/db.png"/>MENU1</span></a>
            <ul  class="menu">
                <li><a href="#submenu11">SUBMENU11</a></li>
                <li><a href="#submenu12">SUBMENU12</a></li>
                <li><a href="#submenu13">SUBMENU13</a></li>
                <li><a href="#submenu14">SUBMENU14</a></li>
            </ul></li>
            <li class="menu"><a href="#menu2" style="height:40px;line-height:40px;"><img src="menu_files/css3menu1/schedule.png"/>MENU2</a></li>
            <li class="menu"><a href="#menu3" style="height:40px;line-height:40px;"><img src="menu_files/css3menu1/analysis.png"/>MENU3</a></li>
            <li class="toplast"><a href="#menu4" style="height:40px;line-height:40px;"><img src="menu_files/css3menu1/gps.png"/>MENU4</a></li>
        </ul>
```

This way you don't have to change the javascript, as the first link in the menu now indeed is the first item of the menu. I leave it for you to find out what works best for you.

Comment: Your second solution works great. This is exactly what I was looking for. The first solution probably requires some additional efforts to make it working, because contents of submenus are merged in this case.

Comment: I had just a very brief look at the script, so there may be some additional changes required to make the first solution work. But I am a bigger fan of the second one, too ;) Anyway, I'm glad it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want something like this: http://www.cssmenus.co.uk/dropdown.html

If you show an example or drawing we could help you even better.

Comment: @JohanB: I attached more detailed code sample. Pls let me know if you'd like also to see the picture.